# Using Simplify on a consistent system returns False

Tags: equation-solving, bugs, simplifying-expressions

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 10.3.**

---

It's late, but am I missing something here?  Why should two independent equations, which together are consistent, `Simplify` to `False`?

```
ClearAll[x, y];
Simplify[y == 0 && x^2 == -1]
(*
  False
*)
```

*Mathematica* thinks they're consistent:

```
Solve[y == 0 && x^2 == -1]
(*  {{x -> -I, y -> 0}, {x -> I, y -> 0}}  *)
```

Individually, each does not simplify to `False`:

```
Simplify[y == 0]
Simplify[x^2 == -1]
(*
  y == 0
  x^2 == -1
*)
```

Such behavior turns up with other equations as well, but the more complicated they are, the less likely it seems that the conjunction will simplify to `False`.  So far I can only get it to happen when at least one of the equations has complex roots.

It seems so basic, I felt like I was missing something.  As I write this question, I'm feeling more and more it's a bug.  Any ideas what is going on?

*V10.1, Mac OSX 10.10.3*

---

Confirmed by WRI (CASE:3370522).

Comment: The same happens in version 8. And it also happens with `Simplify[x^2==-1||y^2==-1]`, as if the variables are inexplicably assumed to be real. I agree this shouldn't happen.

Comment: The problem does not appear if the equations are entered as a list: `Simplify[{y == 0, x^2 == -1}]`

Comment: In version 5.2 (which I luckily still keep) there's no problem Simplify[y == 0 && x^2 == -1] (* y == 0 && x^2 == -1 *). Hence we notice a "regression" from 5.2 to 8 and 10.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Very interesting. Now I regret that I deleted version 5.2 just a few weeks ago...

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I just restored version 5.2 and can confirm that `Simplify` leaves the expression unchanged there (on Mac OS X). This seems to indicate that the bugs tag is warranted here, and it should be reported to Wolfram.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for investigating the issue.  I have reported it just now.

Comment: Shall we add the bugs tag?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I just added the bugs tag since people seem to agree.

Comment: @ Jens : you will surely benefit from following my hint to 5.2. I noticed in several occasions that that was a very good version, especially I don't want to miss it in Integrate[] where it has often higher performance than 8 and 10.

Comment: It works correctly in V7.  Incorrectly in V9.0.1.  So it seems the bug was introduced in V8 and persists through V10.1.  (Please correct if I'm mistaken.)

Comment: I don't know if someone has mentioned already that (1) Simplify[y==0&&x^2== a] with an unspecified symbol "a" returns the argument unchanged, and hence Simplify[y==0&&x^2== a]/.a->-1 gives what is to be expected. (2) Simplify[y == 0 && x^2 == -1 + x] replies correctly although x cannot be real. (3) it seems that any possible way to express the constant 1 (Sin[pi/2], Exp[0], Sqrt[1], ...) leads to the same false result. (4) x^2=I works out fine.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I think it fails whenever `x^2 == z` for any negative, real, numeric `z` and works correctly on all else.  E.g. your `a`, `-Infinity`, `I` or  `-I`, etc. all work correctly.  But not `x^2 == -GoldenRatio` etc.  It also works correctly on `(x+1)^2 == -1`.  So far, the bug seems confined to a very narrow range of examples, but perhaps not a very uncommon examples.

Comment: Looks like it's been fixed as of 10.3

Comment: @Pillsy You can fix the header if you like. My institution still hasn't gotten around to letting us upgrade yet, so I can't check it myself. :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to summarize my understanding: First of all, the documentation states that `Simplify` assumes that variables are real when they occur algebraically in inequalities. Clearly, there are no inequalities in the logical expression `y == 0 && x^2 == -1`, and therefore `x` and `y` should be assumed to be general complex numbers. *If* they were real, then the simplification to `False` would be justified, because `-1` has no real square roots.

When an expression can evaluate to `True` or `False` for different generic values of the variables, consistent with the assumptions, `Simplify` should leave it unevaluated. This is the case here if `x` and `y` are complex.

It therefore appears that the presence of `And` in the expression erroneously triggers the assumption of reality. The same happens when `Or` is present, as seen here:

```
Simplify[y == 0 || x^2 == -1]

(* ==> y == 0 *)
```

This simplification is only correct if one assumes `x` to be real so that the second clause is `False`. To see this, look at the result of `Refine` instead:

```
Refine[y == 0 || x^2 == -1, x ∈ Reals]

(* ==> y == 0 *)
```

The documentation states that `Refine` is one of the transformations called by `Simplify`. But without the assumption above, we get the correct result

```
Refine[y == 0 || x^2 == -1]

(* ==> y == 0 || x^2 == -1 *)
```

This means that before calling `Refine`, there is some processing inside `Simplify` that amounts to adding the assumption `x ∈ Reals`.

Whatever this additional processing is, it was absent in version 5.2 and is present in versions 8 and above. This fact leads me to conclude that it's a bug.

**Also:** the bug can't be removed by *explicitly* stating the assumption of complex variables:

```
Simplify[y == 0 || x^2 == -1, x ∈ Complexes]

(* ==> y == 0 *)
```

Comment: I think this issue is related to my problem as well: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87305/whats-wrong-with-simplify-and-fullsimplify