# What's wrong with Simplify and FullSimplify?

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions, core-language

I have a quite complex list of equations and inequalities I combine to a boundary condition for my cost function. After investigation of two days I found the ***bug*** (I really name it a bug!). One of my equations gets ***simplified*** to ***False***, which is not the desired result!

This is one inequality which drives me crazy!

```
eq = 0.0055356626 + 0.000029 x + 0.000034 y <= 1000.;
```

All coefficients are machine numbers:

```
MachineNumberQ /@ Select[Level[eq, {-1}], Head[#] == Real &]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Because my variables are real numbers and greater than zero, I have added this assumption to my list of inequalities and equations.

On my system (Win7,64bit, Mathematica 10.1.0  for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 24, 2015))

```
Simplify[eq, Assumptions -> {x>0, y>0}]
```

yields **False**!

```
Simplify[eq]
```

just yields `1. x+1.17241 y<=3.44826*10^7`, which is ok.

I have tried different settings for `ComplexityFunction`, but I still get **False**!

Running

```
TableForm@Table[Simplify[eq/.x_Real:>n*x,Assumptions->{x>0,y>0}],{n,1,20}]
```

gives an **interesting** result:

```
False
False
False
False
1. x+1.17241 y<=3.44826*10^7
False
False
False
1. x+1.17241 y<=3.44826*10^7
1. x+1.17241 y<=3.44826*10^7
False
False
True
False
True
False
True
1. x+1.17241 y<=3.44826*10^7
True
1. x+1.17241 y<=3.44826*10^7
```

**I really don't understand this!** **What can I do?** Is there something totally wrong with my equation setup?

I have restarted the Kernel twice and tested this on two computers: I get the same result.

Could anyone please verify this on other OS and version? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Wolframalpha also shows *False*, but the evaluation seems to involve complex numbers:

[image: Wolframalpha]

**UPDATE 2**

Using the Assumption `{x>=0, y>=0}` is working fine ?!

Comment: V8 returns True, and V9 and V10 return False (Win8.1-64). IMHO the result should be neither True nor False. Looks like a bug indeed. Have you contacted support@wolfram.com?

Comment: Not yet. I will contact them soon. BTW, FullSimplify gives the same result.

Comment: Confirmed on Linux. v8.0 gives `True`, v9.0, 10.0, 10.1 gives `False`.

Comment: Note that `Refine[eq, {x>0, y>0}]` gives slightly different results, and not all correct.  Another workaround seems to be to use arbitrary precision numbers: `N@Simplify[SetPrecision[eq, $MachinePrecision], Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0}]`.  (V10.1, Mac OSX)

Comment: Support case #3373364

Comment: still not working under 10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extended comment:

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

```
eq = 0.0055356626 + 0.000029 x + 0.000034 y <= 1000.;

eq // Simplify
```

> 1. x + 1.17241 y <= 3.44826*10^7

Use of assumptions reproduces the problem:

```
Simplify[eq, {x > 0, y > 0}]
```

> False

However, use of `Rationalize` avoids the problem with using assumptions

```
Simplify[eq // Rationalize[#, 0] &, {x > 0, y > 0}]
```

> 616842869 (29 x + 34 y) <= 616839454366000000

Which is equivalent to the original

```
% // N // Simplify
```

> 1. x + 1.17241 y <= 3.44826*10^7

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It's easier for me to add the SetPrecision approach from Michael E2 to my specific problem, but your answer is totally correct. In parallel, I will wait for the support case to be finished.